# How to read the label of a drive or volume in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file to rip my dvds to the hard drive. I'd like the file names to be the volume label of the dvd, but I haven't been able to determine a way to read the label of a disk in a batch file.

Is there a way to retrieve the volume label of a drive in a batch file so I can use it as the file name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for /f "tokens=1-5*" %%1 in ('vol') do (
   set vol=%%6 & goto done
)
:done
echo %vol%
```

Comment: That correctly sets %vol% to the label of the current volume. Just have to switch to the dvd drive before calling it.

Comment: @jColeson - Yes, you will have to change to you dvd drive, easily done by adding a `cd <drive_letter>:` at the top of you batch file.

Comment: You may directly insert the drive in the vol command: `VOL D:`

Comment: There is a small bug in this solution: **it always adds a trailing space** to `%vol%`. This might confuse further script processing.
The blanks around `&` should be removed to get rid of it. I.e.: `set vol=%%6&goto done`

Answer (score 5):

More fully. Programmed as a subroutine we have

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions
set target_=D:
::
call :IsDeviceReady %target_% isready_
echo Device %target_% ready: %isready_%
if /i "%isready_%"=="false" (endlocal & goto :EOF)
::
call :GetLabel %target_% label_
echo The label of Volume %target_% is %label_%
endlocal & goto :EOF
::
:IsDeviceReady
setlocal
set ready_=true
dir "%~1" > nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 set ready_=false
endlocal & set "%2=%ready_%" & goto :EOF
::
:GetLabel
setlocal
for /f "tokens=5*" %%a in (
  'vol "%~1"^|find "Volume in drive "') do (
    set label_=%%b)
endlocal & set "%2=%label_%" & goto :EOF
```

Originally from http://www.netikka.net/tsneti/info/tscmd101.htm#label

Comment: robust one. like it :-)

Comment: Remark: The sub routine "IsDeviceReady" will return false upon an empty drive (which is not correct). Replace "dir "%~1" >nul 2>&1" by "vol "%~1" >nul 2>&1" to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The *vol* command will give you the volume name in a MS SHELL